# How to avoid "Potential Security Risk Ahead" warning for a redirected domain

Tags: browser, https, warnings

I used to have a website at, let's say, "https://someone.com" (please note the SSL), but now I need to redirect it to "https://facebook.com/someone"

I have no files at the hosting since I am not planning to host nothing but to redirect to Facebook.

I already made the redirection at DNS settings in GoDaddy, but people who has my previous address in their browsing history write the URL and the browser automatically takes the historical https version of the domain, resulting in displaying the "Potential Security Risk Ahead" warning.

How can this be avoided to make the correct redirection in previous visitors browsers?

Or, will this history with https in their browser vanish with time? I think not.

Thanks!